# Check constraints-1

Tags: sql, check-constraints

I am wondering about unclear point to me when I am defining check constraint on the column in a table as following :

```
Create test 
(
emp_id number(8) ,
salary number(9,2) constraint test_sal_check CHECK(salary>0,emp_id between 0 and 9)
);
```

In this case its correct to use the emp_id column within   the  constraint  on salary column .

please help me

Comment: Huh?  Do you get some error?  Do not understand the question.

Comment: *"In this case its correct to use the emp_id column within the constraint on salary column ."* You really want salary to be greater than zero for *only* 10 employees? Negative salary is ok for the other employees?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which database you're using, but [Microsoft SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#check-constraints) says:

> A **column-level `CHECK` constraint can reference only the constrained column**, and a table-level `CHECK` constraint can reference only columns in the same table.

[PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) says:

> A check constraint specified as a **column constraint should reference that column's value only**, while an expression appearing in a table constraint can reference multiple columns.

[Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52180) says:

> The syntax for inline and out-of-line specification of check constraints is the same. However, **inline specification can refer only to the column** (or the attributes of the column if it is an object column) **currently being defined**, whereas out-of-line specification can refer to multiple columns or attributes.

As you can see, they all agree, although PostgreSQL might be more lenient (using "should").

Also, the `CHECK(expr)` argument is an *expression*, which means that the `,` comma is not valid.

You have multiple choices:

```sql
CREATE test (
  emp_id NUMBER(8)   CONSTRAINT test_emp_check CHECK(emp_id BETWEEN 0 AND 9),
  salary NUMBER(9,2) CONSTRAINT test_sal_check CHECK(salary > 0)
);

CREATE test (
  emp_id NUMBER(8),
  salary NUMBER(9,2),
  CONSTRAINT test_sal_check CHECK(salary > 0),
  CONSTRAINT test_emp_check CHECK(emp_id BETWEEN 0 AND 9)
);

CREATE test (
  emp_id NUMBER(8),
  salary NUMBER(9,2),
  CONSTRAINT test_check CHECK(salary > 0 AND emp_id BETWEEN 0 AND 9)
);
```

If you meant the constraint to mean "salary > 0 *when* emp_id between 0 and 9", then do this:

```sql
CREATE test (
  emp_id NUMBER(8),
  salary NUMBER(9,2),
  CONSTRAINT test_sal_check CHECK(salary > 0 OR emp_id NOT BETWEEN 0 AND 9)
);
```

Comment: I understood your point  by the examples you mentioned  and now the check constraint its clear to me

Comment: @oraclejunior1 Then you should click the check mark next to the answer to accept it, so others will know that the question has been answered to your satisfaction.